# Taking input from user in Access Database while opening it

Tags: ms-access-2007

in my database there are fields of type Date/Time, their default value is set to now(). But the problem is that those fields are automatically filled up by English system date. I want my own country's date format, without changing my system date format. So I decided, whenever database is opened it should ask for a date, so the user will give today's date and that date will be used automatically on those fields.

But I dont have any idea how to do it, please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a form to display when the database opens which will collect the date.

Click the big menu button in the upper left hand of Access.

From the menu select Access Options on the vary bottom.

From within Access Options, select Current Database on the left menu.

Look for the the fourth line down "Display Form:"

Choose the form you just created.

When you open the database this form will always open and the user can enter the current date.